# The only answer on a bountied question

Tags: support, answers, bounty

If my answer is the only answer on a bountied question, do I still get the bounty even if my answer is not accepted?

Comment: Note that accepting an answer for a bounty is completely separate from accepting an answer with the green check mark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *will* get it if you posted it during the bounty and has a score of 2 or higher; see the [Help Center](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/bounty):

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount

If you posted it earlier, or the score is not high enough, you're out of luck ...